# Bootstrap sticky-top class not work inside main-content class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alert, sticky

I have one problem with sticky-top class of bootstrap.

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="sticky-top">
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        Success
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

bootstrap `main-content` class has `overflow: hidden`, so sticky-top class doesn' t work.

I must have `main-content` class, but I have to use sticky-top class too.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you "have to have" both classes? And what is the end goal here? what outcome do you expect?

Comment: I want to show sticky alert. And i have to use main-content because this is required for theme layout. Please teach me.

Comment: You can override **main-content**'s overflow property. (`overflow: unset`)

Comment: Thanks. @DebsmitaPaul. It works. But are there any other solution? Without customizing main-content class. And how can i thank you?

Comment: Great! I will post it as an answer then. May be you can take `page-content` class, make it to the same height as the `main-content`, then use it as container of `sticky-top`. It might work, I haven't checked it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you cannot use **sticky-top** class with a container having `overflow: hidden` and you HAVE to use **main-content**, you can unset the `overflow` property of **main-content**. Like so

```
.main-content {
    overflow: unset;
}
```

Comment: I will use this solution. But are there any problem cause by customizing main-content?

Comment: Depends on how you are using **main-content**. I mean, is the overflow property needed for your design structure? If no, then there should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks very much for your kind answer. I want to keep in touch with you. You are a first person for my question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yay!! Great to hear that! happy Coding ✌✌